# Confluent CLI on WSL

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, wsl-2

I've built a Confluent Platform using moded Docker on my private Windows 10 machine. Now I want to play around with Confluent CLI and for that I've set-up my WSL and started ubuntu.

`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10`

After opening linux terminal and running `curl -sL https://cnfl.io/cli | sh -s -- -l` I get `command not found` after evoking `confluent`.

What should be else checked ony my side?

Comment: Confluent cli doesn't interact with Docker, though

Comment: So to interact with each Confluent container I simply execute `docker-compose exec broker` command?

Comment: Assuming you need to run commands within the container, then yes

Comment: Look at this page https://docs.confluent.io/confluent-cli/current/install.html , how to install Confluent CLI latest version. And you really having Curl and SH installed in WSL. Also if you behind firewall/VPN probably your Curl command not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this commands:

1. curl -sL --http1.1 https://cnfl.io/cli |  sh -s -- -b ~/Downloads/
2. sudo mv ~/Downloads/confluent /usr/local/bin/

From this your confluent CLI tool should be installed on WSL Ubuntu and you can point to your local dockerized Kafka broker.

I experienced problems (permission related) trying to install from the
Confluent documentation, so this worked for me, instead.